# How to select a Radio Button?

Tags: python, radio-button, mechanize

I am using `mechanize` and I am trying to select a button from a radio button list. This list has 5 items. How can I select the first item? Docs didn't help me.

```
>>> br.form
<ClientForm.HTMLForm instance at 0x9ac0d4c>
>>> print(br.form)
<form1 POST http://www.example.com application/x-www-form-urlencoded
<HiddenControl(DD=17010200) (readonly)>
<RadioControl(prodclass=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])>
<SubmitControl(submit=text) (readonly)>>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[It should be as simple as](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/forms.html)

```
br.form['prodclass'] = ['1']
```

I prefer the more verbose:

```
br.form.set_value(['1'],name='prodclass')
```